# Javaクラス内に定義されたInterfaceのClassを、インターフェース名から取得する方法

Tags: java

以下のように、内部にstaticなインターフェースがいくつか定義されているクラスにおいて、
インターフェース名からクラスを取得したいのですが、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか。

```java
public class XxxForm implements Serializable {
    public static interface GroupA {}
    public static interface GroupB {}
           :
}
```

具体例として、XxxFormのインスタンスと、Interface名（"GroupA"）を引数に
interfaceのクラス（XxxForm.GroupA.class）を取得するメソッドを作りたいと考えています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

簡単に思いついたのは、以下のような取得方法。

```
 public class Questions69135 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        XxxForm xxx = new XxxForm();
        Class<?> class1 = findInnerClass(xxx.getClass(),"GroupA");
        
        System.out.println(class1.equals(XxxForm.GroupA.class));
    }

    private static Class<?> findInnerClass(Class<?> klass, String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return Class.forName(klass.getName() + "$" + name);
    }
}
```

Class.forName を使う方法で大丈夫なのか心配ですが